# How to Use Cloud Custodian on Windows 10

Tags: cloudcustodian

I am trying to get started with Cloud Custodian (AWS) on using Win10. I have Python 3.9 installed, I've run

- python -m venv custodian
- .\custodian\scripts\activate
- pip install c7n

all 3 commands complete with no issues, however if I try to type "custodian", I get "custodian is not recognized as an internal or external command"

I've tried all 3 steps in CMD and Powershell.

What am I missing?

Comment: Search this site for the error message *not recognized as an internal or external command*. This question (and many very similar ones) has been asked and answered here many times before. Always do at least a basic search before asking a new question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

first create a folder and then install
1.python -m venv custodian
2..\custodian\scripts\activate
3.pip install c7n

then start the custodian by using this cmd =>.\custodian\scripts\activate
then it will work..